# Has_many collection method returns empty array if I create the child object through another parent object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, belongs-to

Sorry for the confusing title, I couldnt explain it better. Feel free to edit it.

I have this structure:

```
class Home < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :reservations

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :reservations

end

class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :home
end
```

Which means that Reservations ar associated to the user that makes the reservation, and the 
home that he is booking.

I am creating the reservations instances like this:

```
user_instance.reservations.create(:home => home_instance, :dates_and_other_data => ...)
```

Using this method, the reservation is properly created in the database, and I can retrieve it (with the rest of the reservations the user has made) with

```
user_instance.reservations
```

But, if I try to retrieve it from the home instance I used as a parameter, like this:

```
home_instance.reservations
```

This returns an empty array. The opposite happens as well (I cannot retrieve the reservation from the user instance if I create it from the homes).

What am I doing wrong?

Aren´t these two sentences the same?:

```
Reservation.create(:user => user, :home => home, :other_stuff)
User.reservations.create(:home => home, :other_stuff)
```

Comment: does user_instance.reservations.first.home_id point to a valid home?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user model has no way of knowing that you just created a reservation from the home model, and vice versa. When you access an association for the first time, ActiveRecord *memoizes* the result of that call, so it doesn't need to call the database each time you subsequently use that association.

```
home_instance.reservations   # This will pull from the databse, and store the
                             # results in a variable.

# This will create a new reservation record in the database.
user_instance.reservations.create(:home => home_instance, :dates_and_other_data => ...)

home_instance.reservations   # We don't go to the database here, since we already
                             # have the stored variable. So we don't see the new
                             # reservation.
```

You can get around this by passing `true` as an argument to a has_many association, like so:

```
home_instance.reservations(true)  # The true forces ActiveRecord to requery the DB>
```

Comment: I see, thank you, I had no idea. So when you assign the instance to a variable, it retrieves that info for the first time? Because in my examples, I didnt call the collection methods first.